# Retrieving tweets from Trump's twitter account

Tags: python, json, api, twitter, tweets

I am trying to retrieve tweets from Trump's twitter account with the Twitter API.
However, I am not getting the maximum amount of 3200 tweets with the code below. When I try another screenname I am getting the 3200 tweets. Now I'm only getting 100-200 tweets (it's different each time). The code I am using is as following:

```
import tweepy
import json

access_token = xxx
access_token_secret = xxx
consumer_key = xxx
consumer_secret = xxx


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

screen_name = "realdonaldtrump"

data = []

for tweets in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name = screen_name).pages():
    for tweet in tweets:
        print(tweet.text)
        data.append(tweet._json)
        
filename = screen_name + "_tweets.json"  
with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: Maybe twitter is limiting you because of excessive use?

Comment: I'm not using twitter excessively, and for other twitter account I can get around 3200 tweets, for trump the number is different each time but far below the 3200...

Comment: Then they've probably limited Trump's account then